# TFVC Delete only Project and now no DefaultCollection sort of

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I am migrating to visualstudio.com for Team Foundation Services, ran through a trial run to import our current repositories and then I went in and deleted the "team project".  When I recreated the Project Now it things the "Collection Name" is the project name instead of "DefaultCollection" ... but only sort of.  I can still use the "DefaultCollection" in the url https://myteam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/.  But when you look in the breadcrumb at the top of the page is says "Team Services
/ ProjectName"

If I go to the "Setting" gear in the top right then the bread crumbs are: "Control Panel > Project Name"

The problem is that now the Import tool for importing to TFVC doesn't work.  It sees the "Collection" as the ProjectName then then fails.  Is this a bug in the Visualstudio.com tfs interface?  Does anybody have any idea how I can get the "DefaultCollection" back?

Thanks

dbl

Comment: This was due to a recent change by MS for VSTS. Are you using OVSMU? Which version?

Comment: The about says v1.0 but it also says "OpsHub Integration Manager Framework-OVSMU-V2.1.0.001" and the install I used was OVSMU-V2.1.0.001.  I'm downloading v2.2.2.001 and will try that.  Thanks

Comment: This updated version worked.  Thanks!  Not sure how to mark this as answered!  It's a mix of the Answer @rerwinRR gave and the comment from Opshub Inc. rerwinPR can you update your comments to include downloading the most current version of OpsHub?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is due to the fact that they are getting rid of default collection

[Merging the concepts of Account and Collection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/04/09/merging-the-concepts-of-account-and-collection/)

and will start to allow multiple collections

[How we plan to enable creating Multiple Collections per Account](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/how-we-plan-to-enable-creating-multiple-collections-per-account/)

I'm not too familiar with the OpsHub tool but any url with default collection should still work if you add it in. 
but perhaps it needs an update.

> First, “DefaultCollection” disappears from the account URL. Naturally stating that we’re changing the format of our URLs can make some feel uneasy about the potential impacts this might have. Any existing link that has “DefaultCollection” in it will be 100% supported after the change and will continue to be supported for a long time to come.